# Ajax returning strange extra html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have several snippets of HTML content that get loaded onto a page based on the current selected region of a world map. Here is what the request looks like:

```
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        // more map config options...
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
        {
            //Post request
            $.ajax('/get_post_data.php', {
                data: {region: region},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#post").html(response);
                }
            });
        }  
    });
```

Here is get_post_data.php:

```
$result = '';

  // Swtich based on region
  switch($_REQUEST['region']) {
    //Asia
    case 'China':
    case 'Japan':
        $result = @include('includes/asia.inc.php');
      break;

    //Africa
    case 'Ethiopia':
    case 'Kenya':
        $result = @include('includes/africa.inc.php');
      break;

  echo $result;
```

And the inc.php files look like this:

```
<h2>Asia</h2>
<p>The article for Asia region</p>
```

When the AJAX runs, the corresponding HTML gets posted to the page, but the paragraph is wrapped in extra h2 tags that I didn't write anywhere, and it posts "1" as a string after the p tags. Here's what the markup looks like after the response:

```
<div id="post">
    <h2>Asia</h2>
        <h2>
            <p>The article for Asia region</p>
            "1"
        </h2>
</div>
```

I have no idea why these two extra things are added to my intended markup. When I look at the response in the console, I see the correct HTML, still with the added "1", but without the h2 tags.

Comment: why are you json_encoding for html output?

Comment: You didn't closed the h2 tag in inc.php.

Answer (score 3):

That's cause you haven't properly closed the `h2` tag in `inc.php`

Should be

```
<h2>Asia</h2>
```

Comment: That is correct, but it doesn't explain the stray `"1"` in the output (which happens because the `include()`d file outputs the HTML instead of `return`ing it).

Comment: @DCoder Is there a better way to reference the HTML I need, or should I try to trim() it?

Comment: slice() rather, not trim

Comment: @JesseDillman: look into the documentation for `include`, and how it handles content outside `<?php` tags. Your HTML markup is being echoed during the `include` and your `$result` does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

You are using json_encode($result);  This is what you are displaying, weird things can happen.

try just echo $result;